# Italic letters in iupac module of chemmacros don't work in acronym definition using glossaries

Tags: glossaries, chemmacros

I am trying to make an acronym list for my dissertation, and I am using the `iupac` module of the `chemmacros` package to do so. I use the single letter commands to type the italics because it is easier than setting the italics for each of the letters. I believe the definitions on the package are actually just `\textit{}` codes for each defined letter. However, these do not work when defining an acronym!  (but it does work when using `\textit{}`). I guess I can just typeset each one with the `\textit{}` command, but I am curious as to why this is the case.

This works:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{DMF}{DMF}{\iupac{\textit{N},\textit{N}-dimethylformamide}}

\begin{document}
    Dissolve in \gls{DMF}. Evaporate \gls{DMF} off.
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{DMF}{DMF}{\iupac{\N,\N-dimethylformamide}}

\begin{document}
    Dissolve in \gls{DMF}. Evaporate \gls{DMF} off.
\end{document}
```

(I tried using `\nitrogen` instead of `\N` and it doesn't work either)

**Edit:**

Same goes with the command `\chemprime`. Using `'` or its definition `\ensuremath{{}^{\prime}` both work.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion problem. `\glsnoexpandfields` will help:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\glsnoexpandfields
\newacronym{DMF}{DMF}{\iupac{\N,\N-dimethylformamide}}

\begin{document}

Dissolve in \gls{DMF}. Evaporate \gls{DMF} off.

\end{document}
```

[image]